# Second order differential equation: missing degree of freedom

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the general equation:

$$ \frac{dP(x,t)}{dt} = D \frac{d^2 P(x,t)}{dx^2} - C \frac{dP}{dx} .$$

I used seperation of variables to get a seperable solution, and that resulted in

$$ \frac{1}{P_t(t)} \frac{dP_t(t)}{dt}  = \frac{1}{P_x(x)} \left[ D \frac{d^2P_x(x)}{dx^2} - C \frac{dP_x(x)}{dx} \right ].$$

I set both sides equal to a constant $m$, to get:

$$ P_t(t) = A e^{mt} .$$

For $x$, I wanted to get a solution from the fourier modes of the system. So I guessed $P_x(x) =A e^{-i \omega x} $ and got a solution as long as

$$ -D \omega^2 + i C\omega  = m.$$

Thus, I say that the solutions are of the form:

$$ P(x,t) = \sum_{\omega}   A(\omega)e^{-i \omega x} e^{i \omega Ct} e^{-D \omega^2 t} $$

but shouldn't I get a second degree of freedom for the solution in $x$? I'm running into trouble down the road from this point, and I think it has to do with the fact that I have only one $m$ for each $\omega$, but I think I might need 2. I'm having a hard time finding the second one though.

I guess Fourier modes might not solve the system in $x$?

Edit: I'd prefer to keep the solution in terms of the Fourier modes of $x$, so if I do solve the quadratic then I would like to somehow get back to the fourier modes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether this help. Since the differential operator is not reducable to a composition of simpler operators, you can look at the exponential solutions of the form $P(x, t)=e^{ax+bt}$, where the constant are to be found by using the equation. Substituting $P_t$, $P_x$ and $P_{xx}$ into the equation 
$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} - C \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$$
we find a relation $b=a^2D-aC$. Thus for any choice of $a$ and $b$ satisfying this equation we will have a solution. You can also use Laplace transform in ether direction, but it requires a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $C$ and $D$ are constant. Transformatio of $x\to\sqrt{|D|}$ makes $D=1$. Let $y=x-vt$ for some constant $v$ to be determined and $Q(y,t)=P(x,t)=P(y+vt,t)$. Judicious choice of $v$ will give you
$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial y^2}.$$